# aligning buttons right using tbfil with extjs 4.1

Tags: extjs4.1

I have the following. I would like the first item 'create' to be aligned to the right.

I've read about using 'tbfill' to align. But i'm unsure how to use this with my implementation.

```
        dockedItems:[                        {
                        xtype:'toolbar',
                        flex:1,
                        dock:'top',
                        items:[
                            {


                                xtype:'button',
                                id: 'ContactCreate',
                                name: 'ContactCreate',
                                text:'Create',
                                action:'create',
                                align: 'right',
                                style: 'float:right',
                                width:'100',
                                iconCls:'icon-add'


                            },
                            {
                                xtype:'button',
                                id: 'ContactSave',
                                name: 'ContactSave',
                                text:'Save',
                                action:'save',
                                width:'100',
                                iconCls:'icon-save'
                            },


                            {
                                xtype:'button',
                                id: 'ContactDelete',
                                name: 'ContactDelete',
                                text:'Delete',
                                action:'delete',
                                width:'100',
                                iconCls:'icon-delete'
                            }


                        ]
                    }
                ],
```

Answer (score 4):

I was thinking that you add the tbfill to an actual item. Here is a working example.

```
                dockedItems:[
                    {
                        xtype:'toolbar',
                        flex:1,
                        dock:'top',
                        items:[
                            {
                                xtype:'button',
                                id: 'ContactSave',
                                name: 'ContactSave',
                                text:'Save',
                                action:'save',
                                width:'100',
                                iconCls:'icon-save'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype:'button',
                                id: 'ContactDelete',
                                name: 'ContactDelete',
                                text:'Delete',
                                action:'delete',
                                width:'100',
                                iconCls:'icon-delete'
                            },
                            { xtype: 'tbfill' },
                            {

                                xtype:'button',
                                id: 'ContactCreate',
                                name: 'ContactCreate',
                                text:'Create',
                                action:'create',
                                width:'100',
                                iconCls:'icon-add'

                            }


                        ]
                    }
                ],
```

Comment: Seems you can also add this to your tabpanel.items:

{
 tabConfig : {
  xtype : 'tbfill'
 }
}